# Django error when filter by date "operator does not exist: date >= integer"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm using django framework with postgresql.
I have virtual environment. My local machine Mac , server is on Debian 10.

```
$ pip freeze
amqp==5.0.6
asgiref==3.4.1
billiard==3.6.4.0
celery==5.1.2
certifi==2021.5.30
chardet==4.0.0
click==7.1.2
click-didyoumean==0.0.3
click-plugins==1.1.1
click-repl==0.2.0
Django==3.2.5
django-celery-beat==2.2.1
django-celery-results==2.2.0
django-timezone-field==4.1.2
greenlet==1.1.0
idna==2.10
kombu==5.1.0
lxml==4.6.3
multitasking==0.0.9
numpy==1.21.0
pandas==1.3.0
plotly==5.1.0
prompt-toolkit==3.0.19
psycopg2==2.9.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.1
python-crontab==2.5.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
pytz==2021.1
requests==2.25.1
six==1.16.0
SQLAlchemy==1.4.20
sqlparse==0.4.1
tenacity==7.0.0
urllib3==1.26.6
vine==5.0.0
wcwidth==0.2.5
yfinance==0.1.60
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class Ticker(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    avg_volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6)
    last_close_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6, default=0)
    last_update_date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.symbol

class TickerData(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    open_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6)
    high_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6)
    low_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6)
    close_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6)
    adj_close = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=6)
    volume = models.IntegerField()
    symbol = models.ForeignKey(Ticker, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='infoset')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.symbol}: {self.date}'
```

views.py

```
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta
from django.db import connection
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404

from .models import Ticker, TickerData

def ticker_data_view(request, pk):
    # dates
    enddate = date.today()
    startdatedays = enddate - timedelta(days=180)

    ticker = Ticker.objects.get(pk=pk)
    ticker_info = TickerData.objects.filter(symbol=ticker).filter(date__gte=startdatedays)
    
    context = {
        'TickerData': ticker_info,
    }


    return render(request, 'tickerdata_list.html', context)
```

When I open page with info

```
DatabaseError at /ticker/2 Execution failed on sql 'SELECT "webapp_tickerdata"."id", "webapp_tickerdata"."date", "webapp_tickerdata"."open_price", "webapp_tickerdata"."high_price", "webapp_tickerdata"."low_price", "webapp_tickerdata"."close_price", "webapp_tickerdata"."adj_close", "webapp_tickerdata"."volume", "webapp_tickerdata"."symbol_id" FROM "webapp_tickerdata" WHERE ("webapp_tickerdata"."symbol_id" = 2 AND "webapp_tickerdata"."date" >= 2021-01-09)': operator does not exist: date >= integer LINE 1: ...a"."symbol_id" = 2 AND "webapp_tickerdata"."date" >= 2021-01...
                                                             ^ HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Can somebody help please.

UPDATE

I think my postgres waiting for date in quotes, like:

```
AND "webapp_tickerdata"."date" >= '2021-01-09'
```

I'd tried it directly , just select with such params and it works.
Maybe I need to change settings in postgress?

Comment: Try this: `startdatedays = (enddate - timedelta(days=180))`. It may seem dumb but i had a similar instance not long ago where this worked

Comment: @Beikeni Unfortunately it didn't help  =(((

Comment: The problem is here `operator does not exist: date >= integer `. You are comparing a date to an integer. Im not sure why it takes a date as an integer but maybe try using a datetime element instead? Like `datetime.today()` instead of `date.today()`. Just to see if the problem is with `date.today()`. If the error persists then you'll know its something else.

Comment: @Beikeni I'd tried it. The same result =(

Comment: @Beikeni I think my postgres waiting for date in quotes, like:

AND "webapp_tickerdata"."date" >= '2021-01-09'
I'd tried it directly , just select with such params and it works. Maybe I need to change settings in postgress?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line

```
date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
```

You use date field but `timezone.now` give you a date and time
Change this like that

```
import datetime 
date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

Or maybe this is work aswell

```
date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now.date)
```

Comment: I'd tried - default=datetime.date.today.  It didn't help.
default=timezone.now.date - get an error 'function' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: Whats the problem with first one?

Comment: DatabaseError at /ticker/2
Execution failed on sql 'SELECT "webapp_tickerdata"."id", "webapp_tickerdata"."date", ...."webapp_tickerdata"."adj_close", "webapp_tickerdata"."volume", "webapp_tickerdata"."symbol_id" FROM "webapp_tickerdata" WHERE ("webapp_tickerdata"."symbol_id" = 2 AND "webapp_tickerdata"."date" >= 2021-01-09)': operator does not exist: date >= integer
LINE 1: ...a"."symbol_id" = 2 AND "webapp_tickerdata"."date" >= 2021-01...
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: You run makemigrations and migrate after changes?

Comment: Yes, i run python manage.py makemigrations and then migrate

Comment: I think my postgres waiting for date in quotes, like:

AND "webapp_tickerdata"."date" >= '2021-01-09'
I'd tried it directly , just select with such params and it works. Maybe I need to change settings in postgress?